# how to read the string and split the data and append to a variable

Tags: python, regex, split

```
`string = "LOpener - 119","L2 Sportime Syosset Open - 100033419","Sport"`
```

I have to read this string and check whether `L1B,L2,L1` is present in stringand append to a variable called level. If there is in string then it should return null

Comment: variable = string.split()[0]

Comment: can u hlp for the above condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

Use regular expresession:-

if input is string,

all occurrence in a single string,

```
>>> s = "L1B Armonk Indoor November L2 Opener - 100165419"
>>> _grp = re.findall('L1B|L2|L1', s)
>>> level = " ".join(_grp) if _grp else ""
>>> level
'L1B L2'
>>>
```

one occurrence in a single string,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "L1B Armonk Indoor November Opener - 100165419"
>>> _grp = re.search('L1B|L2|L1', string)
>>> level = _grp.group() if _grp else None
>>> level
'L1B'
>>>
```

if input is tuple,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "L1B Armonk Indoor November Opener - 100165419","L2 Sportime Syosset Open - 100033419","Sportime Syosset Open - 1000567419"
>>> " ".join(re.search('L1B|L2|L1', i).group() if (i and re.search('L1B|L2|L1', i)) else '' for i in string)
'L1B L2 '
>>>
```

or

```
>>> string = "L1B Armonk Indoor November Opener - 100165419","L2 Sportime Syosset Open - 100033419","Sportime Syosset Open - 1000567419"
>>> level = " ".join(i.split()[0] if i and i.split()[0] in ['L1B','L2','L1'] else '' for i in string) # you can replace '' with None if you want
>>> level
'L1B L2 '
>>> 

your `string` definition will give it as a `tuple`
```

Comment: thanks Mohideen bin Mohanmmed it worked well,Now if string "L1B Armonk Indoor November L2 Opener - 100165419"if it has both L1B,L2 it shuld get append to the variable,but this current logic brings wteva present in first fr ge fr abv string L1B willbe in varibale but I want L2 so variable should have both L1B,L2

Comment: thats what i have asked yesterday.. above logic will get one at a time and it can be any part of string.. 

so i need a clarification, a single can be n number of occurrence? is it so?

Comment: so change regex into re.findall() from re.search()
i have modified my answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Split string into data and append L1B to variable

**Code**

```
string = 'L1B Armonk Indoor November Opener - 100165419'
var = string.split()[0]
print(var)
```

**Result**

```
Out[1]: 'L1B'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting.

```
string = "L1B Armonk Indoor November Opener - 100165419","L2 Sportime Syosset Open - 100033419","Sportime Syosset Open - 1000567419"


variable = []

for str in string:
     if 'L1B' in str:
             variable.append('L1B')
     elif 'L2' in str: 
             variable.append('L2')
     elif 'L1' in str:
             variable.append('L1')
     else:
             variable.append('null')

print (variable)
```

Comment: @kavi could you explain your question... and yeah, for every element in the string you will have a null been appended if the condition satisfies.